# Why is the work top clipping out when i got to camera view?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera

[image][full render[image: ][1]]The camera's location and rotation shouldn't cause it and it only happens in camera. I am the noobiest of noobs so please be polite and patient with me. I'm sure you will all say just scale it down but i really don't want to. Image of problem, worktop clipping out in corner behind monitor.[image: Render clipping problem]Trying to add more pics from other angles but can't seem to so sorry for that. Probably to old for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess it would be the camera clipping “end” isn’t set to a high enough value try changing it from 100.000 to 200.000 see if that works, under camera properties.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you, as easy as that may have seemed for you I've spent a fair bit of time moving lighting, adjusting camera angles, blah blah. Never once looked into camera properties! Thanks for the fast reply. FIXED

Comment: No problem something I just spotted in your screenshots